# REACTJS redirecting + 5 second timeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, timeout

Im fairly new to reactjs and can't figure something out. I am trying to build a webpage that redirects after 5 seconds but can't seem to figure out how. If anyone has any tips for me where I can find out how to do this it would be really appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: Well I tried to push history and get it to the correct path but for some reason my computer won't let me use history even though its in the sed folder. I am just exploring new methods of achieving the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

That's something you can do with plain JavaScript. It would look like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.replace('some-url');
}, 5000);
```

Depending on when you want to fire that, you can put it in some component's ["lifecycle method"](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) or even just simply add it at the beginning of your JS file or in ['DOMContentLoaded' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: This was very helpful thank you, I am trying to make it goes over few pages every 5 seconds this just works for one. Ant tips on how I can make it for a few pages?

Comment: If you mean redirect every 5 seconds from one page to another then every page you're redirecting to has to do the redirect on its own. I'm assuming now you're redirecting to your subpages so depending on your app structure you fire the timeout for example when the parent component mounts.

You can also make use of the answer from your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63396358/7511858 and check out `react-router`. You can setup your timeout redirects based on the matching location.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful !

Answer (score 1):

```
const nav = useNavigate();
useEffect(()=>{ 
    setTimeout(()=> nav('/login'),5000);
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your use case but you can simply do that using `setTimeout`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

and you want to have this in `componentDidMount()`.

read more about lifecyles here https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html